# Measuring memory consumption of a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memory

How do you measure the memory consumption of a thread in C#?

The scenario I'm looking at is that a program is trying to solve some hard search problems, it kicks off a thread to look for a solution to one of them, the thread runs for a while, maybe it finds a solution, or maybe it runs over its memory allowance and therefore fails. But to implement that, it's necessary to find out how much memory the thread (as opposed to the entire process) is using. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Threads share a common heap, but have their own stack.

Rather than trying to obtain the memory consumption for a particular thread(you cant do) you would be better off profiling your solution using Visual Studio Memory Profiler or use Ants Memory profiler to help find potential memory issues you're facing.

Does your application spit out any exceptions?

Comment: Right, to clarify, the reason for high memory consumption is not a bug in the program but inherent in the nature of trying to solve problems e.g. theorem proving where the best known algorithms consume a large amount of memory for some smallish problem instances. But if there is no way to do it, then there is no way. Maybe I should be looking at running separate processes instead.